# Error with MODIS download in R

Tags: r, modis

I hope somebody knows this error message, since I managed before the downloading with the same script (last year):

```
source("ModisDownload.R")
mrtpath <- '/home/usuario/MRT/MRT/bin/'

modisProducts()
```

Product to download is MOD11A2, no 31

```
x <- 31 

H <- c(10)
V <- c(10)

Date <- c('2016.02.01','2016.03.02')

try (ModisDownload(x=x,h=H,v=V,dates=Date,mosaic=F, proj = T, MRTpath = mrtpath, bands_subset="1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0",proj_type = "UTM", utm_zone=18, datum ='WGS84', pixel_size = 500))
```

producing this error:

```
***Error in strsplit(unlist(lapply(strsplit(items, "href"), function(x) { :
  argumento de tipo no-carácter***
```

This error is part of the script Modisdownload.R, which I didn't changed.
Any ideas??

Comment: Hi there, welcome to GIS SE. Please visit the tour page to familiarize yourself with the forum. Note, that this question has been asked previously in many instances.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `"ModisDownload.R"`, this script is from 2014. Use **rts** package with [`ModisDownload()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rts/versions/1.0-38/topics/ModisDownload) function (updated Aug 2017).

Answer (score 0):

Unless you provide the original script/debug what is going wrong with the same, you might want to think about using functions from a CRAN package such as MODISTools. That said, here's an example:

```
library(`MODISTools`)
data(SubsetExample)
MODISSubsets(LoadDat = SubsetExample, Products = "MOD13Q1", Bands =  c("250m_16_days_EVI",
"250m_16_days_pixel_reliability"), Size = c(0,0), StartDate = TRUE)
```

Refer to the [package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MODISTools/MODISTools.pdf) for more details.